# best practice to handle ObjectId while convert cayenne generated class to other layers

Tags: apache-cayenne

usually, java developers convert objects between layers. for example from application domain objects to persistent entities and vice versa. however, apache cayenne use ObjectId to represent keys in database, and it's a combination of entity name and keys in map, so I would like to know what is the best practice to map ObjectId to other layers. In fact, I am using ObjectId in my POJO right now, but I don't know if it is applicable. Thanks...

Comment: There's no single right answer. It depends on your app. If you could explain the purpose of that POJO layer, it will be easier to give advice about the id.

Comment: the purpose of that POJO layer is used to generate JSON for restful services. I need id in POJOs because I may use values of POJO to update database. I am used to JPA and I usually have one or multiple attributes in POJO to represent key, but ObjectId is a little different because it's entity name + map. So the convenient way for me is to use ObjectId in POJO, just want to know if it is applicable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your POJOs goal is to mirror JSON, the main consideration here should be your REST API convenience for the consumer.

While on the Java side, having a semi-opaque ObjectId is often a good idea, in JSON REST API I would suggest to "unpack" the ID map into individual properties. Hence the POJO would also need those properties.